# does x = User.all create a hash? How do I traverse it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Let's say I have a User table and a Messages table, they have a has_many belongs_to relationship. I want to find the id: for users who's names are "Bob", then pull the message history for one of the id's.

```
x = User.where(name: "Bob")
```

Does that create a hash in variable x, with all the results of users whose names were Bob?  The result in the console certainly looks like a hash when I run x. To includes the messages tied to all the Bobs, I think I do:

```
x = User.where(name: "Bob").includes(:messages)
```

Now that I have x...how do I find the id's of the people whose names are Bob? I don't want to query the db again, I'd like to do it all via the variable, is that possible?

I then want to get the first message of the first id (the first Bob) in my table. Can that be done via the variable, or do I have to go back to the DB once I have the first id?

Thanks for all the help guys and gals!

Comment: Thank you for the edits @Mischa!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most ActiveRecord queries return a `Relation`.

You can call `x = x.to_a` to make rails perform the actual query(there will be 2 SQL queries - one for users and one for messages) and then traverse the resulting array.

Comment: This is it! Thanks Vasfed

Answer (score 1):

This will do it. As referenced in the rails guides. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html section 13.2

```
x = Message.includes(:users).where(users: { name: "Bob"})
```

and then to get the first message just tack on .first at the end of the query.

```
x = Message.includes(:users).where(users: { name: "Bob"}).first
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to query from Message, not User. Joins (inner join)  and includes (left outer join) can be used for eager loading, like in your question, or to do query across multiple tables.

```
Message.joins(:user).where('user.name = "bob"')
```